# Css works for html checkbox control and not for asp.net checkbox control

Tags: css, asp.net, checkbox

I have this html checkbox with css applied to it.

Here is the jsFiddle.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dRYhk/)

It works perfectly , the problem is when i am trying to apply the same css to asp.net checkbox, it is not working.

Here is the code for html input control.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkReservaSemanal" id="chkReservaSemanal" class="css-checkbox" runat="server" /><label for="chkReservaSemanal" class="css-label">Week</label>
```

And here is the code with asp.net.

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSemanal" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkSemanal_CheckedChanged1" CssClass="css-checkbox"/>
```

But when applied to asp.net checkbox it is not working.

The css is on the jsFiddle.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the css-class to the input element of the `CheckBox`-control? Therefore you can use the [`CheckBox.InputAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.inputattributes(v=vs.110).aspx)-property: `chkSemanal.InputAttributes["class"] = "css-checkbox"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the rendered code from ASP.NET. The CssClass that you define is added to a wrapper around the input and label controls.

So you can add css rules to compensate:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox,
.css-checkbox input[type=checkbox] { ... }
```

Or you can use code behind to attach the class names to the label and input controls separately:

```
chkSemanal.InputAttributes["class"] = "css-checkbox";
chkSemanal.LabelAttributes["class"] = "css-checklabel";
```

Comment: I added this in pageLoad but now i cant see the checkbox.

chkSemanal.InputAttributes["class"] = "css-checkbox";
chkSemanal.LabelAttributes["class"] = "css-checklabel";

Comment: Check the rendered result in the developer tools and fix it. It's hard to tell you what went wrong without seeing the rendered result. Perhaps you could put the rendered result into a fiddle. But IMO, you should use the first approach; you don't really want to add code behind everywhere you use this!

Comment: The rendered result is:
<input id="chkSemanal" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'chkSemanal\',\'\')', 0)" name="chkSemanal">

<span id="lblSemanalChk" class="help-block " style="display:inline-block;width:163px;">Semanal</span>

Comment: Notice the rendered result is showing a `<span>` instead of `<label>` (which is what the CSS is expecting). Is this span coming from the `<asp:CheckBox>` control's Text property, or do you have an explicit `<asp:Label>` right next to your checkbox?  ...in your fiddle, if you change the span to a label and give it a css-label class it works as expected.

Comment: Malk it doesnt work because when you click it doesnt change anything.

Here is the jsFiddle, anyways i cant make it render a label cant i?

http://jsfiddle.net/aPN5A/

Comment: Labels need a `for=<name>` attribute to bind them to a control. Add `for="chkSemanal"`.

Comment: A label is rendered when you set Text on the Checkbox (`<asp:Checkbox Text="Semenal" .../>`) or when you set an AssociatedControlId on a label (`<asp:Label AssociatedControlId="chkSemenal" ...  />`)

Answer (score 1):

Web controls in the  System.Web.UI.WebControls namespace may render differently in different browsers. You can't count on them rendering the same elements always. They may add anything that they think is needed to make it work in the specific browser.

For example, an asp checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox    ID="CheckBox1"    runat="server" CssClass="myClass" />
```

May render with a span:

```
<span class="myClass"><input id="CheckBox1"    type="checkbox" /></span>
```

as you can see it's the span who have the classname and not the input type checkbox.

The best way to render it as you want is to use:

```
CheckBox1.InputAttributes.Add("class", "myCheckBoxClass")
```

Just to say:

```
CheckBox1.CssClass
```

will render the same way as adding a CssClass attribute and may add spans.

Hope this would be helpful, I faced this problem before and this is one of the ways to solve it.

Comment: I added the following line in the pageload, but all that is visible when i execute the page is the label of the checkbox.

chkSemanal.InputAttributes.Add("class", "css-checkbox");

Answer (score 1):

As the asker didn't mention how he got it working, I'll share the solution suggested by @MALK:

```
<span class="css-checkbox">
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Click me!" CssClass="css-label" AssociatedControlID="CheckBox1"></asp:Label>
</span>
```

And to prevent style lost after a PostBack, in the Page.Load event:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load        
    Me.CheckBox1.InputAttributes("class") = "css-checkbox"
    Me.CheckBox1.LabelAttributes("class") = "css-checklabel"        
End Sub
```

Best regards.